# Change Appearance of the values that returned form database (DOT NET)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-core

I would like to change the appearance of the values that are returned from the databases as I wish. After modifying the values, I would like to assign this appearance to View Model

e.g. I have a **Model** that contains these field
*ID, Username,HistorDay,Clock.*
**View Mode**
*ID,Username,HistorDay, check-in, check-out*

I want to group by Username and HistorDay if Clock index % 2! = 0 (even) insert this value to check-in
else index % 2 == 0 (even) insert this value to check-out

For More Details -->
I try this

```
var Filter = _context.Attendances
             .GroupBy(x => new { x.Username, x.HistorDay }) 
             .Select(x => new {
           Username = x.Key.Username, 
           HistorDay = x.Key.HistorDay,
           In = x.Select(c => c.Clock).Where((q, w) => w % 2 != 0),
           Out = x.Select(c => c.Clock).Where((q, w) => w % 2 == 0),
});
```

but get Exception System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Eams.Models.Attendance]'

I try this code form Svyatoslav Danyliv

```
var rawData = _context.Attandances
              .Select(a => new { a.Username, a.HistorDay, a.Clock })
              .ToList();

var result = rawData
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.Username, x.HistorDay })
            .Select(x => new 
            {
                Username = x.Key.Username,
                HistorDay = x.Key.HistorDay,
                In = x.Select(c => c.Clock).Where((q, w) => w % 2 != 0).ToList(),
                Out = x.Select(c => c.Clock).Where((q, w) => w % 2 == 0).ToList(),
            });

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"ALL {item}");
        }
```

in console --> Result ==>

ALL { Username = 43091, HistorDay = 6/23/2023 12:00:00 AM, In = System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.TimeSpan], Out = System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.TimeSpan] }

Comment: Maybe it is enough to get first record of the group as `In` and last as `Out`? I don't know nature of your data.

Comment: Nah I know how can take 1st record and last record but I wanna take all record in this day and filtering clock filed in(Check-in) and out(Check-out) ... i try developing attendance management system

Comment: IMHO this odd / even pairing of records is a view concern. Not something that should be performed in the database, or that the data layer needs to know anything about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your query it is needed to select minimal data from form database and then post process on the client side:

```cs
var rawData = await _context.Attendances
  .Select(a => new { a.Username, a.HistorDay, a.Clock })
  .ToListAsync();

var result = rawData
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Username, x.HistorDay }) 
    .Select(x => new {
        Username = x.Key.Username, 
        HistorDay = x.Key.HistorDay,
        In = x.Select(c => c.Clock).Where((q, w) => w % 2 != 0).ToList(),
        Out = x.Select(c => c.Clock).Where((q, w) => w % 2 == 0).ToList(),
});
```

Comment: This is right Special thank to Mr Svyatoslav Danyliv and to all the colleagues here

Answer (score 0):

"Value Conversions" can be used if you are using "EF Core". That's the best way to do it. Here's an example and how to use it
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations